# Why this error : type mismatch; found : Unit required: String => Unit

Tags: scala

Below code :

```
object gen {
  println("Welcome to the Scala worksheet")

  case class CS(funToRun: String => Unit)

  val l: List[CS] = List(

    CS(open("filePath"))

    )

  def open(path: String): Unit = {
    java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop.open(new java.io.File(path))
  }
}
```

causes compiler error :

```
type mismatch; found : Unit required: String => Unit
```

But my open function is of of type `String => Unit` and param type of funToRun is `String => Unit` ?

Comment: It looks like you want `CS(open)` instead of `CS(open("filepath"))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CS` accepts a function from `String` to `Unit`, but you're passing to it the result of `open`, which is `Unit`.

If you want to pass it `open` as a function instead, you need to do:

```
CS(open)
```

although without knowing what you're trying to achieve, it's impossibile to provide a sensible solution.

A possible alternative for performing the `open` action at a later time

```
case class CS(funToRun: () => Unit) // the function is not taking parameters any longer
val cs = CS(() => open("filePath")) // 'open' is not performed here
cs.funToRun() // 'open' is performed here
```

This way the `open` function is not evaluated when passed to the `CS` constructor.

Comment: how should "open" be initialized with String ?

Comment: what do you mean by "initializing"? If you pass a `String` you will just be calling the function. If you intend to have a closure on the string, you can simply wrap the whole thing inside a thunk (i.e. a lambda with no arguments). I'll show an example in the answer